# Passing data up the components hierarchy in Modern React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In a react component hierarchy one can pass data from the root component to   some component inside component tree by passing `props`. But what is the optimum way of passing data up the hierarchy? I can think of passing methods from the wrapper to the child. Is there any better way of handling data flow in a deep nested components scenario?

Comment: Perhaps look at [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) maybe? (I haven't used it before but have heard it's good for state management)

Comment: you can use state management lib for that like redux,flux,mobox etc

Comment: @pouya yes for i.e D  will dispatch an action with payload,that action update store, and updated store is available to B

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is something wrong with passing callback functions from parent to child component.

But, in this case:

```
<parent onSomeEvent={..}>
  <first-child onSomeEvent={..}>
    <second-child onSomeEvent={..}>
```

...

When need to pass some data from child component to higher level parent, and you don't want to pass the callback function like above example you may use state management like [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux), [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html). You can also use [react context api and hooks](https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/) if you don't want to use additional library.

You just have to keep in mind it isn't overkill for your app.

Comment: thanks so basically there are three options 1- passing methods 2- using a state management library 3- using context api and hooks and which one is preferred

Comment: It basically depends on you application complexity, i.e. if the app is very simple and you don't have lots of this kind of boilerplate, and you basically don't need state management you may use option 1. But if you are using some of those state managements anyway I think it is better to pass the information in this way. 
Also if you write this app for learning purpose you can implement it in each way just for practice.